# JavaPairRDD iteration using traditional java for loop

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

how to iterate JavaPairRDD using java traditional for loop?
with foreach we can iterate, but am looking with traditional for loop

Comment: You should not need to do that. And try to avoid doing that, if possible. `RDD`'s are distributed data strcutures, any transformations on them run on the "worker" nodes. For this "traditional for loop" thing, you will first need to accumulate the whole `RDD` as a traditional Java collection on a single node (this is the driver node).  Driver nodes are a shared resource for all jobs running on Spark cluster. You will likely cause memory overflow erros not only for your own job but other jobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `JavaPairRDD` to `List<Tuple2<>>` by calling `collect()` method on RDD. After this you can use traditional for loop to iterate. I would not recommend this since `collect()` brings all records to driver node and cause OOM issues in case there is no enough memory.

```
List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> tuple = Arrays.asList(new Tuple2<>(1, "a"),
        new Tuple2<>(2, "b"));

JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> pairRDD = sc.parallelizePairs(tuple);

List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> listRDD = pairRDD.collect();

for (int i = 0; i < pairRDD.count(); i++) {
    System.out.println(listRDD.get(i));
}
```